# Can someone identify this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I have no idea what this plant is. My friend owns it. [image]

Comment: Are stems square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is borage, which is a type of herb. In India we use it to make fritters (chop the leaves and make a thick batter with chickpea flour and water, mix in the leaves and salt, then shallow fry by dropping teaspoonfuls into hot oil). It's also used for medicinal purposes, e.g, for congestion due to a cold.

Comment: Sorry, you also need to add a pinch of turmeric